# Can we use regex in robots.txt file to block URLs?

Tags: robots.txt, regular-expression

I have a few dynamic generated URLs.

Can I use regex to block these URLs in a robots.txt file?

Comment: It would also be worth setting [robots meta tags](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) on the pages you don't want crawled/indexed.

Comment: @AndrewLott In my case I have more then 500 page, so I thought use regex in robots.txt..

Comment: Then a rule in your site code is probably more helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Regular Expressions are not valid in robots.txt, but Google, Bing and some other bots do recognise some pattern matching.

Say if you wanted to block all URLs that have a `example` any where in the URL, you can use a wild card entry *

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*example
```

You can also use the dollar sign $ to specify that the URLs must end that way.  So if you wanted to block all URLs that end with `example`, but not URLs that had a`example` elsewhere in the URL you could use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*example$
```

More in-depth info for Google can be found here: [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), Bing here: [How to Create a Robots.txt file](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-file-cb7c31ec) and there is a an interactive guide on Moz [here](http://moz.com/blog/interactive-guide-to-robots-txt)

Comment: Perfect, * is working fine, Tested in web master tool.. Thanks Max...:)

Comment: I'd caution from using too fancy directives in your robots.txt file; these are really, really hard to debug later on. Try to keep things as simple as possible. Also remember that robots.txt is case-sensitive, so you may need to add alternate versions of the directives depending on your site.

Comment: would be nice if regex was supported

Comment: I tested your example and googlebot doesnt recognize that,i made example.php and put some code in it,also wrote regex as in your example and when i tested url in GSC report dont tell me than url is blocked by robots,txt.

Answer (score 3):

For blocking urls by regular expressions not from *crawling* (downloading) but from *indexing* in search engines you can use

https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

dynamic adding of HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag` into **mod_rewrite** rules of Apache (or nginx) that widely supports regular expressions.

Comment: Isnt usefull when we have spam url-s on hacked website.