# Wildcard matches in robots.txt that allow crawling of all JS and CSS are not working

Tags: robots.txt

To allow the robots to crawl all CSS and JS files we have used the following code:

```
Allow: /*.css$
Allow: /*.js$
```

But, some CSS and JS are still being blocked as stated when using the mobile friendly test from Google.

Does the location of the line of code in the robots.txt file matter?

Are there instances were the line of code will be ignored?

Comment: Valid code but impossible to answer without futher information. We know nothing of the error message reported by Google Console (was it a fetch test or was it a index warning). What exact file and location was it complaining about? and what other rules do you have in your robots file, since these could be relevant.

Comment: Note that you don't ordinarily need to `Allow` anything, since that is the default action. The fact that you have `Allow` directives to begin with suggests that you have other `Disallow` directives. We would need to see your entire `robots.txt` file. It's quite possible that you have more _specific_ `Disallow` directives that are taking priority.

Comment: As stated, I used the mobile friendly test from Google, this stated that files were blocked, all the files ended in css and js, some were 3rd party, some were not. From the below answers, I have found the issue is because of the length of the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robots.txt uses the longest rule that matches.   So when your rules are

```
Disallow: /directory
Allow: /*.js
```

Then `/directory/file.js` would be blocked.   Both rules match, and the longer one (the disallow rule) takes precedence.  See [this article](https://www.deepcrawl.com/blog/best-practice/disallow-and-google-an-intermediate-seo-guide/#a-matching-allow-directive-beats-a-matching-disallow-only-if-it-contains-more-or-equal-number-of-characters-in-the-path) which explains it.

One work around might be to use lots of stars in your wild card rules to make them longer than your other rules:

```
Allow: /********************.js
```

Here are some screenshots from Google's robots.txt testing tool showing the technique working:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "One work around might be to use lots of stars in your wild card rules to make them longer" - However, Google states... "[The order of precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records)" - which could mean that current behaviour might change in the future?

Comment: Yes, Google appears to leave the door open to changing the behavior.  Other crawlers might also implement it differently so it would be good to test with tools from Bing, Yandex, and Baidu to see if they do things the same way.

Comment: This was my issue, I had rules that were longer so took priority. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not supported in robots.txt and this was [asked awhile back on Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/can-we-use-regex-in-robots-txt-file-to-block-urls). However the code that you have provided is valid which [will match certain paths and files](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#example-path-matches). According to Google's bot it defines:

*Using `/*.js$` matches:*

- `/jquery.js`
- `/scripts/jquery.js`

*Using `/*.js$` would NOT match:*

- `/jquery.js?ver3.0`
- `/jquery.js/`
- `/jquery.JS.MIN`
- `/jquery.JS`

If you are using versioning or any other format that is not supported then you can be less specific by using simply `/*.js` without the `$` on the end.

Since your code looks correct the issue you have is likely something else or a rule that is conflicting with your current ones you have. You should be as specific as possible and look at any rules that could be conflicting with them.

See:

> [Order of precedence for group-member records](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records)
>
> At a group-member level, in particular for allow and disallow
>   directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path]
>   entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule. The order of
>   precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined.

Comment: The linked document simply refers to these special meta characters as "wildcards".