# Disallow URLs with an ID from being crawled

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have a website with around 100K URLs. I want to disallow crawling for all URLs that have an ID with this pattern:

`www.example.com/node/sport/category/id`

but not those without the ID:

`www.example.com/node/sport/category/`

How can I approach this in a *robots.txt*?

**UPDATE:**
the ID are some numbers like `/12343/` or `/12345/` etc

Comment: Which parts of these URLs are placeholders? i.e., does the URL actually contain "category" or is this a placeholder? And if so, how many categories are there? And what is the structure of "id"?

Comment: Do you specifically want to prevent _crawling_, or would it be sufficient to just prevent _indexing_? The later you could do with a few directives in `.htaccess` to inject an `X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow` HTTP response header when an appropriate URL (matched by regex) is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a lot of great options.  *robots.txt* rules are usually prefix matching.

One option would be to change all of your URLs that end in an id so that they have a common prefix: `/node/sport/category/` would get crawled but `/private/node/sport/category/id` would not because you would add `Disallow: /private/` to *robots.txt*.

The major search engine bots (Google and Bing) do support pattern matching in robots.txt files.   Unfortunately, they [don't support regular expression matching](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/can-we-use-regex-in-robots-txt-file-to-block-urls), so you are limited much less powerful globs.  Even the globs won't be supported by most other crawlers, so this will only work for major search engine bots, not for all crawlers.  I think the best you can do is disallow URLs ending in digits with 10 different rules:

```
Disallow: *0$
Disallow: *1$
Disallow: *2$
Disallow: *3$
Disallow: *4$
Disallow: *5$
Disallow: *6$
Disallow: *7$
Disallow: *8$
Disallow: *9$
```

Another option is to allow those URLs to be crawled, but prevent them from being indexed.  Instead of changing your *robots.txt* file, you could add a meta tag to those documents so that search engines won't index them after they get crawled:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Comment: You could perhaps be more specific and only block a _minimum_ path depth, eg. `Disallow: /*/*/*/*0$` etc. (to match the `/<node>/<sport>/<category>/<id>` path depth).

Comment: I will need to add one entry for each of the unitary numbers? 1,2,3,4, etc? like/<node>/<sport>/<category>/*0$ then the same for 1, 2, 3, etc? that would work for 39383 or 1238437? thanks for your help

Comment: `*0$` means ends with zero.  So it would be fine for IDs 10, 200, 34760, etc.  Ten rules should cover all possible IDs.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this your `robots.txt` can contain the following lines

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/*/*/id
```

You can also test this in the robots.txt checker in the old search console

Comment: I think "id" is standing in for some digits (ie a number).  This isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes if the ID means a digit then this wont work

Comment: Yes... the ID are some numbers like /12343/ or /12345/ etc etc